# In Python, how to represent a class in the same way named tuple does?

Tags: python, class, namedtuple, repr

I initially wrote some code, making use of a named tuple:

```py
from collections import namedtuple


Count = namedtuple('Count', 'input_number multiple_of count remainder')


def get_count(input_number: int, multiple_of: int) -> Count:
    '''
    >>> get_count(100, 10)
    Count(input_number=100, multiple_of=10, count=10, remainder=0)
    >>> get_count(5, 6)
    Count(input_number=5, multiple_of=6, count=0, remainder=5)
    >>> get_count(999, 90)
    Count(input_number=999, multiple_of=90, count=11, remainder=9)
    '''
    count = input_number // multiple_of
    remainder = input_number % multiple_of
    return Count(
        input_number=input_number,
        multiple_of=multiple_of,
        count=count,
        remainder=remainder
    )
```

NOTE: How when the object is printed, it is of format: Count(input_number=100, multiple_of=10, count=10, remainder=0) for example.

**Is there a Pythonic / best practice way to represent ordinary classes in the same way?**

I then wanted to incorporate the typing features of python3.6+ and found I couldn't do that with namedtuple from collections, so I edited the Count class to the following:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple


class Count(NamedTuple):
    input_number: int
    multiple_of: int
    count: int
    remainder: int
```

I wasn't quite happy with needing two functions so I started new with:

```py
class GetCount():
    '''
    >>> GetCount(100, 10)
    GetCount(input_number=100, multiple_of=10, count=10, remainder=0)
    >>> GetCount(5, 6)
    GetCount(input_number=5, multiple_of=6, count=0, remainder=5)
    >>> GetCount(999, 90)
    GetCount(input_number=999, multiple_of=90, count=11, remainder=9)
    '''

    def __init__(self, input_number: int, multiple_of: int):
        self.input_number: int = input_number
        self.multiple_of: int = multiple_of
        self.count: int = input_number // multiple_of
        self.remainder: int = input_number % multiple_of
```

What is the best way to get the output in the way I expect (please see doctests for expected output).

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem is the following:

```py
class GetCount():
    '''
    >>> GetCount(100, 10)
    GetCount(input_number=100, multiple_of=10, count=10, remainder=0)
    >>> GetCount(5, 6)
    GetCount(input_number=5, multiple_of=6, count=0, remainder=5)
    >>> GetCount(999, 90)
    GetCount(input_number=999, multiple_of=90, count=11, remainder=9)
    '''

    def __init__(self, input_number: int, multiple_of: int):
        self.input_number: int = input_number
        self.multiple_of: int = multiple_of
        self.count: int = input_number // multiple_of
        self.remainder: int = input_number % multiple_of

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({', '.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in self.__dict__.items()])})"
```

You can see that the provided tests pass by running the below:

```py
import doctest
doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```